# ASP.NET GridView RowCreated add a row dynamically

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a dynamically bound GridView control and I want to add a row after the bound one, but I can't imagine the way to do it.

Inside the GridView.RowCreated I have this code:

```
                Dim gvr As New GridViewRow(0, -1, DataControlRowType.DataRow, DataControlRowState.Normal)
                Dim thc As New TableCell
                thc.Text = "Text"

                gvr.Cells.Add(thc)

                GridView1.Controls(0).Controls.Add(gvr)
```

It is working well, butit is inserting a row before the databound row. Please, is there any way to insert the dynamic row after the databound?

Comment: could you do it in RowDataBound event.

Comment: I was tried that, but the row is rendered also before the databound row

Comment: do you want to add a row after all the databound rows??? please edit the question and provide an example for clear understanding of your requirement.

Comment: What is unclear? I need to add row after each databound row. Behavior of this code is the same for  RowCreated or RowDatabound event.

Comment: @GaganDeep I'm sorry, you were right. I forgot to test for header row in the RowDataBound so it looks like the row was inserted before. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the first parameter of the constructor is the row index.

```
Dim i as Integer = gvr.Row.Count
Dim gvr As New GridViewRow(i, -1, DataControlRowType.DataRow, DataControlRowState.Normal)
```